# UPI Deeplinking from IONIC to GooglePay does not work as expected

Tags: ionic3, deep-linking, webintents, upi, google-tez

We have developed an IONIC based mobile app to perform In-App payment using UPI. It uses IONIC Native Web Intent plugin. 
a.  
b.  "@ionic-native/web-intent": "^4.14.0",

This is shim layer for the Android intent mechanism and makes web intent call to BHIM/PhonePe/GooglePay

It works well with all UPI apps like BHIM, PhonePe. But does not work with GooglePay, For some reason with same code , **Google Pay returns NULL Intent** to OnActivityResult() even though the UPI Payment is successful.

2. I wrote similar functionality in a sample **Native Android app** and tried payment with GooglePay and it works
3. So I am baffled. I did debug my IONIC app and that is where I found that after GooglePay payment is successful, the call back returns to Android and then to Cordova and then to my application. It seems either Intent code of Android or GooglePay code is sending null Intent to caller app.

Appreciate any feedback on this.

Thank you and warm regards

Haresh Gujarathi

Comment: I am trying to integrate my Ionic App with BHIM, can you suggest me a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the code i'm using in my Ionic project for UPI payment in Android. I'm able to get response from Google pay. I have tested this with Paytm, Whatsapp and Google pay.

```
// I'm using this to open the app user has choosen to pay with
private packages = {
  'paytm': 'net.one97.paytm',
  'google': 'com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user',
  'whatsapp': 'com.whatsapp'
};
// Deep link URL
const url = 'upi://pay?pa=<UPI ID>&pn=<Payee name>&tr=<Transaction ID>&tn=<id>&am=<amount>&cu=INR';
// Deep link options
const options = {
  action: this.webIntent.ACTION_VIEW,
  url,
  package: this.packages[serviceName]
};
// Open the intent with options
this.webIntent.startActivityForResult(options).then(console.log, console.error);
```

Comment: shouldn't transaction id should be a response after the completion or rejection of the payment?

Comment: I'm getting it fine from google pay. But not from whatsapp, paytm

Comment: how to know whether payment success or failure when we use the above code. Can anyone explain?

Comment: @sanjayKumar how will you get to know what UPI app user has selected? Where do you fill the value of serviceName variable?

Comment: @sachinrathod You can present the packages to user in some form of UI and then based on user selection you can choose the package.